# How can I get my rails controller (CREATE) to accept/POST multiples JSON records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest

I have a backend Rails JSON API. Right now, I am only able to create one record per POST based on the way I've coded my controller.

Let's say we have an application where Users can create To-Do Lists and in those lists they can create items.

3 models for our example, User, UserList, and UserListItems

User has_many UserLists

UserLists has_many UserListItems

Now right now, I'm updating UserListItems with a POST, but I can only add one item at a time. The JSON looks like...

```
{
  "user_list_item":
  {
    "item_title": "Buy Milk"
  }
}
```

And using Active Model Serializers, I am returning the record that it creates, and it looks as follows...

```
respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_list, user_list_item, location: nil, serializer: Api::V1::UserListItemSerializer

{
  "user_list_item": {
    "id": 11,
    "user_list_id": 2,
    "item_title": "Buy Milk"
  }
}
```

There is a serious flaw with this. If a User creates a 'Grocery To-Do List' and we POST 1 UserList record... that's fine. But then they might begin to fill the grocery list and add 3 things at once. "Buy Milk", "Buy Eggs", "Get Gas". We now need to POST to UserItemList 3 times, and that's far from ideal. What if they added 20 items. We should aim to add all 20 in 1 POST.

How can I do this?!?

1) Can someone show me the entire sample code for the CREATE in the controller to do this, as I learn best by seeing/doing syntax. I want to be able to pass in...

```
{
  "user_list_item":
  [
    {
      "item_title": "Buy Milk"
    },
    {
      "item_title": "Buy Eggs"
    },
    {
      "item_title": "Get Gas"
    }
  ]
}
```

and have my controller parse, loop, and create them. 2) And I also want to be able to return the record(s) to the creator via Active Model Serializers. So for example, all 3 of these newly added records in one return (mostly I'm just interested in the first thing right now though).

**EDIT**: Adding my original controller#create code

```
    if authenticate_user
        user_list = @current_user.user_lists.find_by_id(params[:user_list_id])
        user_list_item = user_list.user_list_items.new(user_list_item_params)

        if (user_list_item.save!)
            respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_list, user_list_item, location: nil, serializer: Api::V1::UserListItemSerializer
        else
            render json: { error: "Could not create new User List Item."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end         
    else
        render json: { error: "User is not signed in." }, status: :unauthorized
    end

private

    def user_list_item_params
        params.require(:user_list_item).permit(:user_list_id, :title, :due_date)
    end
```

Now, with @Arvoreniad's suggestion below, I now have the following...

```
    if authenticate_user
        @user_list = @current_user.user_lists.find_by_id(params[:user_list_id])
        @error = false

        user_list_item_params[:user_list_item].each do |attribute|
            item = @user_list.user_list_items.new
            item.title = attribute.title
            item.due_date = attribute.due_date
            @error = true unless item.save
        end

        if (error)
            ????????????????
        else
            render json: { error: "Could not create new User List Item(s)."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

private

    def user_list_item_params
        params.require(:user_list_item).permit(:user_list_id, :title, :due_date)
    end
```

My new questions are

**1)** Where all the ?'s are... where I was previously using ActiveModelSerializers to show the newly added record, how can I return something showing all the newly added records? Or this that not typical of an API? Is it just common to return something empty and just go off of whether it was successful or not?

**2)** Can-I/Should-I create both things in 1 POST (UserList and Multiple UserListItem's all in 1 POST)? If so, how?

**3)** How can I rollback all saves if one does not work. Let's say I'm trying to add 10 items, and 9 succeed but 1 fails, how do I roll them all back?

Comment: Could you please supply your existing controller code?

Comment: @Arvoreniad Yes, I have added it to the end of my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to answer without your previous controller code, but this should give you a starting point based on the info you supplied. EDIT: Added the code for points 1 and 3. 
If you want to create a UserList in the same action, just post the required data and create one from the parameters, rather than finding it in the database. I can help you with this if you'd like, but it shouldn't be too hard.

```
def create
  @user_list = UserList.find(params[:id) 
  @error = false # Use this to check before rendering if there has been an error.

  params[:user_list_item].each do |attributes|
    item = UserListItem.new
    item.item_title = attributes.item_title
    item.user_list_id = @user_list.id
    @error = true unless item.valid?
    @items << item
  end

  if(@error)
    render json: { error: "Could not create new User List Item(s)."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  else
    @items.each do |item|
      item.save
    end

    serialized = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@items, each_serializer: UserListItemSerializer)
    render json: serialized
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added my original controller code to end of my original post. I seem to have everything implemented with your answer, except I'm not sure how to pass the result for more than 1 save to Active Model Serializers. I'll describe in a bit more detail in my original post EDIT.